# advanced c or c++ book

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

what is the most advanced c or c++ book you ever read?
i am asking this because i already read lots and lots of books on c and c++ on a lot of topics including (object oriented programming-data structures and algorithms-network programming-parallel programming (MPI-PThreads-OpenMP-Cilk-Cuda)-boost library....). So whats next. I still want to advance.. especially in c.

Comment: You might want to check this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74405/what-is-the-best-c-book-for-an-intermediate-to-expert-developer

Comment: I don't know about *"most advanced"*, but take a look here in the *"intermediate"* or *"above intermediate"* section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list is like the wiki of questions like these.

Answer (score 17):

Scott Meyers:

- [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)
- [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)
- [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)

Comment: +1 - exactly what I would have said.

Comment: Meyers' books are excellent, but I wouldn't call them "advanced". That's pretty much "must-know" for competent C++ programmers.

Comment: Don't read it once. Read it six times and commit all the advice he gives in those books ( particularly Effective C++ ) to memory.

Comment: there is also Effective STL: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1320267819&sr=1-1

Answer (score 10):

[Modern C++ Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design)

Comment: Scot Meyers' books are easy to read, useful and, well, effective. Modern C++ Design, on the other hand, is mind-blowing :) (You may not want to write code like that routinely so that you don't blow too many minds---of programmers who read your code. But it's worth reading the book nevertheless.)

Comment: Definitely read this book, but beware of the problems with the Loki library. It is more like a proof of concept. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299166/loki-functor-problem-with-memory

Answer (score 8):

(For C) [Expert C Programming: Deep C secrets](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Expert-Programming-Peter-van-Linden/dp/0131774298/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1266779847&sr=1-1) without a doubt.

Comment: I liked the book a lot. Not a pedantic tomb laying out technical details. Very readable and interesting. Teaches more than juts C.

Comment: Great book! Highly recommended. +1

Comment: Absolutely, I give all my staff a copy of this book when they start.

Answer (score 4):

The [C++ Standard](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470846747.html). You cannot get any more advanced than this.

Similarly for C, there must be a book on the C99 standard, perhaps this page will help: http://careferencemanual.com/

Comment: *C: A Reference Manual* is indeed a very good treatment of the C standards.

Comment: To the downvoter: The question asked for _most_ advanced C/C++ book. One could claim that such a book is the standard!

Answer (score 3):

My favourite "difficult" C++ book is this Template Metaprogramming one: [C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255).

Answer (score 3):

[Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/book/main.html) by Andrei Alexandrescu.

Explains a few design patterns in detail, and explains how powerful C++ can be.

Comment: +1 One of the few programming books which I've actually found really interesting (the other ones being the rest of the series :).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there aren't half as many books about C programming as there are about C++. The language just isn't that complex.

One interesting read might be [P. J. Plauger *The Standard C Library*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099). It is supposed to contain some masterful code. It's on my to-read list.

Comment: Norman Ramsey: That good, huh?

Answer (score 2):

The ubiquitous [Stevens "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment"](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of advanced, and whether you are focused on the languages themselves or topics is / using those languages (C / C++).

- [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) in C - *not say this is good style usage, just advanced material*
- [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) by Steven Skiena
- Advanced Compiler Design and Implementation by Muchnick
- Optimizing Compilers for Modern Architectures by Allen & Kennedy

Of course a *Zen style* answer would be to study non-C/C++ languages to learn more about C/C++. Smalltalk, Lisp, Scheme, Haskell, Python, Prolog, or Forth for example of languages from a different programming paradigm, which could expand your approach for development in general.

Comment: +1 All great suggestions. I'd also add 'Realtime Collision Detection' by Christer Ericson and 'Hackers Delight' ( can't remember the author off hand )

Comment: Numerical recipes is by no means advanced material. Apart from the fact that the C++ style is really bad (it isn't the point of the book though), the whole book must be known perfectly by anyone who routinely writes numerical code. There are many more numerical methods which build on top of this.

Comment: Not only is Numerical Recipes not advanced reading, it's also not a good source for the problems, algorithms, or implementations that it discusses: http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/Fortran/numrec.html

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Stepanov and Paul McJones, ["Elements of Programming"](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/).

Comment: It is the best book I've read (I re-read it whenever I can) not only about C++ but programming in general

Answer (score 0):

[Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) by Bjarne.

It's nice to know the history of some features. Makes it much easier to understand why and how stuff works, and thus also easier to remember and explain to others why some things are the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

[Large Scale C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) by John Lakos.

Practical advice on managing the complexity of compiling/linking and executing large C++ programs. Talks a lot about decoupling and how to avoid the many kinds of dependencies that arise in C++.

(This is something most C#/Java developers, and sadly some C++-devs too, rarely understand.
IMO, it's a pain they need to. I wish we had modules in C++ already.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would consider these advanced, but I would surely put them in the category of must have references:

[The C++ Programming Language Special Edition (3rd) by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735)

[The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference by Nicolai M. Josuttis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260)

The other books I would recommend have already been listed by others.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to test your mental limits? Then try these:

[Alexandrescu: Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

[Abrahams&Gurtovoy: C++ Template Metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255)

These books look deceiptively thin, but they stretch the limits of template programming, your C++ compiler, and your brain.

Answer (score 0):

Hey nobody mentioned about **Bruce Eckel's Thinking in C++ [Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139798099) And [Volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130353132)**. When I read it as the first book it went straight way above my head. However as now I have good experience and have read books like Effective/Exceptional C++ so Eckel's book is now an ordinary stuff. However no doubt its a very popular book (4.5 stars on Amazon - 84 customer reviews).